# d3 issue: .data() is not recognizable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm learning d3.js and I'm having a problem pushing a simple data from a csv file.
The error at the console is:
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data"

Apparently, the compiler can't identify the method .data() from d3. The one we call to iterate the svg elements:

```
const circles = svg.selectAll("circles").data(data);
```

Before this statement, I called the data like this and it is showing normally on the console.

```
    d3.csv("data/HousePricesAroundtheWorld.csv").then((data) => {
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.number = Number(d["annual percent change"]);
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

[Link to the repo](https://github.com/micazev/mastering-d3/tree/main/projeto-1)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `data` is only accessible inside of the function that you are passing to `.then()`. One option is to create a function that draws your chart. This function can have one parameter for the chart's data. You can pass this function to `.then()` so that it gets passed the data read from the file. Here's an example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
        d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curran/data/gh-pages/uci_ml/iris/iris.csv', d => ({
          ...d,
          description: `${d.class}: ${d.petal_length} x ${d.petal_width}`
        }))
          .then(chart);

        function chart(data) {
           d3.select('#chart')
             .selectAll('p')
             .data(data)
             .join('p')
               .text(d => d.description);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```